# Is there a CORS support for Office 365 Management API?

Tags: azure, office365api

Is there a CORS support for Office 365 Management API?

I know it has support for mail, calendar and contacts API. But when I try to call Management API through client side code it ended  with CORS error as below.

Error:
SEC7120: [CORS] The origin 'https://mysite.sharepoint.com' did not find 'https://mysite.sharepoint.com' in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header for cross-origin resource at 'https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0//activity/feed/subscriptions/list'.

My Ajax call is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
url:"https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/<tenant_id>/activity/feed/subscriptions/list",

method: "GET",

crossDomain: true,

headers: {

"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",

"Content-Type" : "application/json;odata=verbose",

"Authorization": "Bearer eyJ0..Tg",

"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
},

success: onQuerySucceeded,

error: onQueryFailed

});

function onQuerySucceeded(response) {

alert('success');

}

function onQueryFailed(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

alert('Error!');

}
```

Please help!! Thanks in Advance!!